# Getting error while envoking rest API URL

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I have created an API in wso2 ESB as:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="getUUIDAPI" context="/getUUID">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="?Name={searchValue}" inSequence="getUUIDIN" outSequence="CommonJsonOut"/>
</api>
```

and it gives me an API Invocation URL as `http://10.224.64.97:8280/getUUID`. Now when i try this rest service in my browser as :

```
http://10.224.64.97:8280/getUUID?Name=uvu
```

, In the esb i get error as :

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2013-06-26 10:25:50,796] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} -  The system cannot infer the transport information from the 
/getUUID?Name=uvu?Name=uvu URL. {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2013-06-26 10:25:50,796] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the /getUUID?Name=uvu?Name=uvu URL.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:115)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:456)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:57)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:316)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:329)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.WSDLEndpoint.send(WSDLEndpoint.java:69)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:306)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:308)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:182)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:204)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

As you can see in the above error the url it is hitting is `/getUUID?Name=uvu?Name=uvu`   but i am sending `/getUUID?Name=uvu`. 
Why i am getting this strange error? If i copy the api file, sequences associated with api to other server's esb and then i hit with above url i get the response.
Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

define something like this;

```
uri-template="/{searchValue}"
```

Comment: I have done like this also ratha but when i invoke the service i.e. /getUUID/uvu again it does the same thing which is /getUUID/uvu/uvu

Comment: Bit weird.. What do you mean by this last statement? "If i copy the api file, sequences associated with api to other server's esb and then i hit with above url i get the response"

Comment: I mean to say that if i copy the api's and sequences and endpoints from one system to another sometimes it works.In my system i have created 10 api's that are working but when i move these api's to server then i get the above error posted in question